# Question about constructing of analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I was revising and encountered some problems. Here is the given theorem

Suppose $f$ is analytic in a domain and let $C$ be the boundary, then

\begin{equation}
g(z)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{f(z)-f(a)}{z-a} \text{ if }z \neq a \\
f^{'}(a) ~~~~~~~~~~ ~~\text{ if } z = a
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

is analytic in the domain also.

However, when i looked back at one of the problems i did for example, i had this function $f(z) = \dfrac{z}{e^{z}-1}$ in the closed ball $|z| = 2$.

Then i claimed the following function $g(z)$ is analytic in $|z| = 2$ without thinking much.

\begin{equation}
g(z)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{z}{e^{z}-1} ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{ if }z \neq 0 \\
f^{'}(0) = 1 ~~~~~~~~~~ ~~\text{ if } z = 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

The problem is when i looked back i found out that i didnt seem to fulfill the criteria to use the theorem? for example, $f(z)$ is not analytic and i did no use $f(z)-f(a)/z-a$

i dont even know if i am using the correct theorem... Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $$f(z) = \frac{z}{e^z - 1}$$ is defined on $\mathbb{C} - \{2 \pi i k \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, since at $2 \pi i k$ the denominator is zero. However, at $z = 0$ there is a removable singularity, and the function is well-behaved there: there is essentially just a hole missing from the function. The $g(z)$ you have defined just patches up this hole, and is analytic on a disc containing the origin, and not intersecting any other pole of the function. In particular, it is analytic on $|z| \leq 2$. Note however that $f'(0)$ is not the correct way to patch the function at $z = 0$, and your value of $f'(0)$ is wrong, but the function $g(z)$ is correct.

The correct way to derive the missing spot is to take the limit
$$\lim_{z \to 0} f(z) = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{z}{e^z - 1} = 1$$

Comment: In case it matters, that $f$ has poles at $2\pi ni$ for every non-zero integer $n$. ;)

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, i usually use your way to derive the limit , however, notice the theorem i put in my question, how come it doesnt coincide with the theorem?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang oops - I'll fix my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @ilovewt It doesn't coincide with the theorem because it isn't in the correct form for the theorem. Since $f(0) = 1$, you should have $z/(e^z - 1) - 1)$ when $z \neq 0$, and $-1$ at $z = 0$.